# PTIJ: Is baldness good or bad?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Psalm 69:5 says "More numerous than the hairs of my head are those who hate me without reason." And Leviticus 13:40 says: "וְאִ֕ישׁ כִּ֥י יִמָּרֵ֖ט רֹאשׁ֑וֹ קֵרֵ֥חַ ה֖וּא טָה֥וֹר הֽוּא׃ -- If a man loses the hair of his head and becomes bald, he is pure."

So being bald is a blessing!

But Ezekiel 7:18 says "They shall gird on sackcloth, and horror shall cover them; every face shall betray shame, and every head shall be made bald."  And Mishnah Bekhorot 7:2 says: "A bald man is unfit [for the priesthood]."

So being bald is a curse!

Which is it?  I am confused...

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Korach and Elisha make it seem that baldness is bad.... might try to work that into a humorous answer if i have time later, but if anyone wants to take this idea and write their own answer please feel free! :)

Answer (score 3):

Baldness is awesome!

As Ezekiel so poetically describes ([1:22](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezekiel.1.22?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi)):

> הקרח הנורא נטוי על־ראשיהם
>
> The awesome baldness, spread upon their heads

So what does Ezekiel mean in 7:18?

You have to read it in context, [starting a few verses earlier](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezekiel.7.15?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi), to understand that that verse is not discussing one who is totally bald, but rather one who inexpertly cuts their own hair, leaving bald patches:

> הַחֶרֶב בַּחוּץ **וְהַדֶּבֶר** וְהָרָעָב מִבָּיִת אֲשֶׁר בַּשָּׂדֶה בַּחֶרֶב יָמוּת וַאֲשֶׁר בָּעִיר רָעָב **וָדֶבֶר** יֹאכְלֶנּוּ ... וְכִסְּתָה אוֹתָם פַּלָּצוּת וְאֶל כׇּל־פָּנִים בּוּשָׁה וּבְכׇל־רָאשֵׁיהֶם קׇרְחָה
>
> The sword is outside and **pestilence** and famine are inside; he who is in the open shall die by the sword, he who is in the town shall be devoured by famine and **pestilence** ... [the barbers are closed due to lockdowns] therefore horror covers them, every face is embarrassed, because every head has bald patches.

(This experience is all too familiar to those of us who had to cut their own hair during the first few months of the covid-19 pandemic.)

As to your question from Bekhorot 7:2, I'm afraid you've mistranslated. It actually reads:

> Korach is unfit for the priesthood

which is, after all, the whole resolution of [the Korach episode](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.16.1-13?ven=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&aliyot=0).

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a nafka minah (practical difference).

One who is completely bald is a no-go but a bald patch is okay.

We see this from Haman - refer to the Gemara in [Megillah 13b](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.13b.18?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=Steinsaltz&lang2=en):

> שֶׁמָּא תֹּאמַר, קָרְחָה אֲנִי עוֹשֶׂה בְּמַלְכוּתֶךָ — מְפוּזָּרִין הֵם בֵּין הָעַמִּים.
>
> Perhaps you will say that I am making a bald spot in your kingdom, (i.e., you fear that if an entire nation is wiped out there will be a desolate area within the kingdom.) There is no need to worry, though, as they are scattered [mefuzarin] among the peoples, (and eradicating them will not result in the creation of an unpopulated zone in the area where they had once lived.)

In other words, you might think that there would be a bald spot i.e. a bad thing, the beginning of the end, but it is okay as there are still few scattered tufts of hair around your head which is still okay!

Comment: no joke.... see rosh AZ 5:11 (quoted in yad yehuda 98:1)

Answer (score 1):

The Midrash Tanchuma in Metzora says

> וְאִישׁ כִּי יִמָּרֵט רֹאשׁוֹ (ויקרא יג, מ). עֲדַיִן יֵשׁ בִּמְרִיטַת הָרֹאשׁ מַמָּשׁ, סָפֵק לְטַמֵּא סָפֵק לְטַהֵר. חָזַר בּוֹ, מוּטָב. וְאִם לָאו, לוֹקֶה בִּשְׁחִין,
>
> Thus it is stated (in Lev. 13:40), “When someone's head becomes hairless...there is a substantial doubt whether he is unclean or clean. For him to repent is preferable,...

We see from this that the idea of baldness is *a machlokes*. A few more sources talking about baldness are also found e.g.

> וְאִם֙ מִפְּאַ֣ת פָּנָ֔יו יִמָּרֵ֖ט רֹאשׁ֑וֹ גִּבֵּ֥חַ ה֖וּא טָה֥וֹר הֽוּא׃
>
> If he loses the hair on the front part of his head and becomes bald at the forehead, he is pure.

so we see that baldness is a sign of purity

Furthermore:

> תִתְגֹּֽדְד֗וּ וְלֹֽא־תָשִׂ֧ימוּ קׇרְחָ֛ה בֵּ֥ין עֵינֵיכֶ֖ם לָמֵֽת
>
> you are not to put a bald-spot

WHich is a biblical statement that shows that it is not lechatchila (preferable) to be bald.

A possible chiluk could be found in the Mishna in Kilayim

> קָרַחַת הַכֶּרֶם, בֵּית שַׁמַּאי אוֹמְרִים, עֶשְׂרִים וְאַרְבַּע אַמּוֹת. וּבֵית הִלֵּל אוֹמְרִים שֵׁשׁ עֶשְׂרֵה אַמָּה.
>
> A bald patch of a giant[one who has been raised (רום)], Beit Shammai say, twenty-four [square] cubits, and Beit Hillel says sixteen [square] cubits.

From this we see that the baldness the torah is speaking about is **only with giants!!!**

Answer (score -1):

Rabbi Akiva was bald, so it must be a blessing.

Comment: So how do you explain Yechezkel and the mishna? Besides, Rabbi Akiva was somewhat mocked for being bald (and that's how we know he was bald in the first place...).

Comment: @Harel13 where do we see he is mocked? - isn't it a compliment?